# What is the best amplify manual deployment approach for your teammate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am using amplify CLI for the deployment procedure of the website.
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/hosting

I use amplify init to create below folders.
[image]

I am thinking to push this folders on Git to share with my teammates for their deployment.

I also set up the script for them to deploy, e.g. deploy-dev/deploy-uat script.
[image]

However, I am thinking of some drawbacks.

1.My teammates may need to run amplify configure/amplify init in order to deploy their work directly on amplify.
2.I may need to expose the aws access key/secret key to them?

Can someone give some advice on it? Is there any better to provide the deployment procedure to my teammates?